# EXCEL Average of column/range A IF column/range B OR column/range C equals NO

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, formula

I can't work this one out. Pretty much as the title says...

How can I get the average of a range or column, if there is a "No" in two other ranges/columns?

To put it another way, I want to calculate an average for column A, and I have two columns which ask a Yes/No question (column B & C). I only want the rows with No/No in B AND C to be included in the average calculation for column A. If B OR C have a yes answer, then I want to EXCLUDE that row from the average calculation for A.

Any idea's? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [AVERAGEIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690) formula to achieve what you want.

> **Description**
>
> Returns the average (arithmetic mean) of all cells that meet multiple
>   criteria.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> AVERAGEIFS(average_range, criteria_range1, criteria1,
>   [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)

So, assuming that

- A1:A8 = numbers range
- B1:B8 = condition1 range
- C1:C8 =  condition2 range
- "No" = condition1 and condition2

**Formula:**

`=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A8;B1:B8;"No";C1:C8;"No")`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need the `AVERAGEIFS` [formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690) that will take a column of values and multiple conditions on whether to include the value of a particular row in the calculation.

See the screenshot:

[image]